# How to write the passive form of the potential form?

Tags: expressions, passive-voice, potential-form

I am curious about the passive form(受動態) of the potential form(可能形).

I thought about using

> （先生に）褒められられる

but it seems awkward, and there are no search results in Google for it.

So is

> （先生に） 褒められることができる

the best form of the expression above?

(for example, 先生に褒められる事が出来るかどうか分からない)

In conversations, how do Japanese people express this meaning?

Comment: ほめてもらえる・・・たぶん・・・

Comment: What exactly does it mean to be capable of being praised?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A purely-grammar-based, "textbook" answer would be 「[褒]{ほ}められ[得]{う}る」.

The chances that you would ever hear/see us say that in a natural setting would, however, be close to 0%.  It sounds pretty wordy and not even completely "natural".

In real life, 「褒めてもらえる」, the phrase given by @Choko above, would be far more natural.

「褒められることができる」 is actually as unnatural as「褒められ得る」.　You could say 「褒めてもらうことができる」, though.

「先生に褒められることができるかどうか分からない。」, therefore, is unnatural if not totally nonsensical.  A Japanese kid might actually say it if he were nervous.

More naturally, you could say 「先生に褒めてもらえるかどうか分からない。」, but since you are talking about your teacher, you may want to use the honorific and say 「先生に褒めて**いただける**かどうか分からない。」.